# LaTex works in meta but does not preview in parent

Tags: support, math-display

I entered various LaTex tags:
$\alpha$
$\log \Lambda_i$
$S_i$
and these all look great here in meta and in the preview.

However, when I enter the same in answering a question in parent, the preview never processes the LaTex tag and leaves them with the dollar signs.

Has anyone seen this behavior?
Should I blindly submit the LaTeX and hope for the best?

This behavior occurs on both Firefox 3.0.19 and 3.6.13.

Comment: Sometimes, when I am composing a response in Parent, the preview simply stops working.  Once the message is posted it's rendered just fine and usually the preview works again when I re-edit it.  Yes, I do wait for the preview; yes, I wait longer when there is a lot of TeX in the document; yes, I click outside the textbox to make sure the preview is not waiting for me for some reason.  This phenomenon is intermittent.  (Firefox 3.6.13 on Win 7/64.)

Comment: Here is a twisty solution that worked. I continued to have the problem of LaTex not displaying in preview, but started a new Firefox tab and new meta question. I fed equations from latex.codecogs.com to the meta question, and then finally cut-and-paste from meta to the real question. It formatted correctly after posting.

Comment: I'm getting this error on the bottom of the page: Failed to load http://stats.stackexchange.com/content/js/third-party/MathJax/jax/output/HTML-CSS/fonts/TeX/fontdata.js . All the formulas are shown as "[Math processing error]" in CV, but not in meta (FF 3.6.13 on Fedora).

Comment: Forget about my previous comment, found the answer here http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/673/firefox-3-6-13-messes-up-mathjax Clearing the cache solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As others have suggested -- try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Good suggestion, Jeff, but this error persists even with a reboot and a new Firefox session. Look at my Jan 7 comment and you'll see a viable workaround.

Comment: @rajah9 I suggest starting Firefox in "safe mode" or temporarily using another browser with a clean install. I suspect you have plugins that are interfering.

Comment: Great suggestion, Jeff, I will try Firefox safe mode next time I see the behavior.